# Dont split String on Space on a csv import

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

Summary: As soon as i have spaces within my CSV my code dont work as intended.

Hi,
im kinda stuck on a self created problem.(im just trying to learn but the use Case is to format an Excel-Sheet to a format which i can import in another applciation)

I Have a CSV as following:

```
EMPTY ;Column1;Column2;Column3;Column4
Line1 ;      x;      x;       ;x
Line2 ;      x;       ;      x;
```

(tryed to clean it up for better reading)

The result is of my code is a new file with the following content:

```
Line1,Column1
Line1,Column2
Line1,Column4
Line2,Column1
Line2,Column3
```

This is exactly what i want.

But as soon as i got spaces in the import file, i cant get the output i need.

For ex: Cloumn 1 instead of Column1 in this csv.

```
        File i_file = new File("import.csv");
        File e_file = new File("export.csv");

        Scanner inputStream;

        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(e_file, true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            inputStream = new Scanner(i_file);

                while(inputStream.hasNext()){
                    String line= inputStream.next();
                    String[] values = line.split(";");
                    lines.add(Arrays.asList(values));
                }

            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        int lineNo = 0;

        for(List<String> line: lines) 
        {
            int columnNo = 0;
            for (String value: line) 
            {
                // System.out.println("Line " + lineNo + " Column " + columnNo + ": " + value);

                if (value.contentEquals("x")) 
                {
                    System.out.println((lines.get(lineNo)).get(0)+" is connected to "+(lines.get(0)).get(columnNo));
                    out.write((lines.get(lineNo)).get(0)+","+(lines.get(0)).get(columnNo));
                    out.newLine();
                }
                columnNo++;
            }
            lineNo++;

        }
        out.close();
```

Hope this doesn't look to ugly.

I Found a similar Problem here where they mentioned to use:

```
    inputStream = new Scanner(i_file);
    inputStream.useDelimiter(";");
    while (inputStream.hasNext())
    {   
        content = inputStream.next();
        System.out.println(content);    
    }
```

with this i am not able to add the Values to the 2d List. 
Cause i havent figured out how to distinguish the different lines.
Also i raed about a solution to use an Array instead of a List but
i think i should work with list because i dont now how big the csv will get.

Is there any easy way that this will work with spacecs like Column1 oder something like "Column1" ?
If not, on what should i research to fix this problem ?

Comment: try `inputStream.useDelimiter("\n")`, add `\r` if your line break includes it. so that scanner can read line by line

Comment: `\n` might not be enough. You might need `inputStream.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n]+"));` to scan your csv line by line.

Comment: @Arvind - the code is still working - the output is just not what i expect

Answer (score 0):

Thanks peekolo,

a first try with your answer looks great.

```
try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(i_file);
        inputStream.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n]+"));
        while (inputStream.hasNext())
        {   
            String line= inputStream.next();
            String[] values = line.split(";");
            lines.add(Arrays.asList(values));   
            // System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println(lines);
        }
```

If i use the code as posted i get as output:

```
[[EMPTY, Column 1, Column2, Column3, Column4], [Line1, x, x, , x], [Line2, x, , x]]
```

Looks exactly like the 2 Dimensonal List im looking for.